# How to have a custom internal server error using react next? (500 internal server error)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, react-router

How to have an custom page rendered when we gotten internal error server 500 like this? 
[default internal server error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE7mf.png)

I use react next js, i have make the _error.js file, and its working on 404 page (The NotFound component get rendered when i go to localhost:3000/asdasdad for example), but when I cannot get the Crashed component rendered when I got internal server error 500
[my _error.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xfrdq.png)

Thank you!

EDIT: Solved, see the answer made by me

Answer (score 1):

turns out we it cant, after run the getInitialProps function, it skips render and goes immediately to the error pages on the question

```
  if(statusCode === 404){
    return <div>error404</div>
  }
return <div/>
}

Error.getInitialProps = ({ res, err }) => {
  const statusCode = res ? res.statusCode : err ? err.statusCode : 404

    if(statusCode >= 500 && statusCode < 600){
      res.writeHead(302, {
        Location: '/error'
      });
      res.end();  
  }

  return { statusCode }
}

export default Error
```

but it can be hacked this way, to redirect the user to error page if its getting 5xx error